# How to use KeycloakRestTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, resttemplate, spring-framework-beans, response-entity

I want to make a Spring Boot client app that can access a OAauth2 secured service. This will be some kind of a proxy. And, this "proxy-service" SHOULD not be secured.

I want to use `KeycloakRestTemplate` for the remote REST calls.

Following the docs: http://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_spring_boot_adapter

So far I included the following dependencies:

```
dependencyManagement {
      imports {
        mavenBom "org.keycloak.bom:keycloak-adapter-bom:3.4.0-FINAL"
      }
    }

    dependencies {
      compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
      compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
      compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
      compile('org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-starter')
      compile('org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-security-adapter')
    }
```

I added a Config Class:

```java
    @KeycloakConfiguration
    public class KeycloakWebSecurityContextConfig extends 
    KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    /**
     * Defines the session authentication strategy.
     */
    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Autowired
    public KeycloakClientRequestFactory keycloakClientRequestFactory;

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public KeycloakRestTemplate keycloakRestTemplate() {
        return new KeycloakRestTemplate(keycloakClientRequestFactory);
    }


    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilterRegistrationBean(
        KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakPreAuthActionsFilterRegistrationBean(
        KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        super.configure(http);
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
    }
```

And made a service component:

```java
    @Autowired
    private KeycloakRestTemplate template;

    @Value("${person-service.url}")
    private String endpoint;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/person", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Collection<Person> getPerson(){
        ResponseEntity<Person[]> entity = template.getForEntity(endpoint, Person[].class);
        return Arrays.asList(entity.getBody());
    }
```

"Person-service" is the secured remote service.

Calling the `getPerson` method gives me:

```bash
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set authorization header because Authentication is of type class 
org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken 
but class org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken is required
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.client.KeycloakClientRequestFactory.getKeycloakSecurityContext(KeycloakClientRequestFactory.java:75) 
~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-3.4.0.Final.jar:3.4.0.Final]
```

I think Spring-Security comes in the way and creates a `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` before the `KeycloakAdapter` has a chance to create its own `SecurityContext`.

So, how do I initiate and use the `KeycloakRestTemplate` correctly?

Comment: No. I couldnt solve it. My plans are to make a little demo app on github and open an issue. But time is low.

Answer (score 8):

The `KeycloakRestTemplate` works when your micro-service was initially called by a logged in user, then from there you can make calls to other protected micro-services.

If you want your micro-service to initiate a call to another protected micro-service you are better off using a `OAuth2RestTemplate`.

The `RestTemplate` below will automatically login to Keycloak with a Keycloak Service Account and renew the bearer token when necessary:

```java
    String url = "https://keycloakserver:8888/auth/realms/testrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token";

    ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
    resourceDetails.setGrantType(OAuth2Constants.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS);
    resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri(url);
    resourceDetails.setClientId("your-micro-service-client-id");
    resourceDetails.setClientSecret("p455word");
        
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails);
```

Comment: Now is necessary add the `org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2` dependency

Comment: I solved it with help from this article: https://medium.com/@bcarunmail/accessing-secure-rest-api-using-spring-oauth2resttemplate-ef18377e2e05
Created the class OAuthResttempalteconfigurer, with the configuration to get the access token from Keycloak. 
Than i just need to inject the OAuthRestTemplate for calling the keycloak secured web service.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you (your client) are not authenticated to Keycloak, hence the missing Keycloak token.

If you are not logged in to Keycloak you should use a simple Rest Template from Spring, instead of the Keycloak Rest Template.

```
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate

...

RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
rt.postForObject(uri, data ,String.class);
```

Comment: I dont get it. When I use the vanilla RestTemplate how can this manage to talk to Keycloak and receive the accesstoken? I mean I managed to write a RequestInterceptor doing this, but I thought KeycloakRestTemplate was designed and created to NOT use a custom RestTemplate. I am confused...

Comment: I got this error when using Keycloak Rest Template while not being authenticated. You probably call your "getPerson()" Method, before your login. You should use the vanilla RestTemplate for the Login. After the Authentication you should use Keycloak Rest Template. This works for me.

Comment: But you are right, except for the login (and register) you should user Keycloak Rest Template

Comment: Sadly this does not apply for my problem. I dont have any web frontend where users can login. I am developing a couple of microservices which should communicate with secured third party applications.

Comment: You can get a token/ a session in java via the Keycloak Admin Client, after that you can use Keycloak Rest Template. You could just log in with a test-user.
https://gist.github.com/thomasdarimont/52152ed68486c65b50a04fcf7bd9bbde

Answer (score 0):

As erhardt correctly describes:

> The KeycloakRestTemplate works when your micro-service was initially
> called by a logged in user, then from there you can make calls to
> other protected micro-services.

The suggestion to use OAuth2RestTemplate was no option for me, because it is deprecated meanwhile.

I ended up using Keycloak Instance:

you need the dependency (build.gradle)

```
implementation group: 'org.keycloak', name: 'keycloak-admin-client', version: '15.0.2'
```

The I wrote a Factory for a RestTemplate:

```
@Component
public class KeycloakRestTemplateFactory {
    @Value("${keycloak.auth-server-url}")
    private String keyCloakAuthServerUrl;

    @Value("${keycloak.realm}")
    private String keycloakRealm;

    @Value("${keycloak.resource}")
    private String resourceClientId;

    @Value("${keycloak.credentials.secret}")
        private String resourceClientSecret;

        public RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate(String username, String password) {
            Keycloak keycloak = Keycloak.getInstance(keyCloakAuthServerUrl,
                    keycloakRealm,
                    username,
                    password,
                    resourceClientId,
                    resourceClientSecret);

            TokenManager tokenmanager = keycloak.tokenManager();
            ClientHttpRequestInterceptor clientHttpRequestInterceptor = (request, body, execution) -> {
                AccessTokenResponse accessToken1 = tokenmanager.getAccessToken(); //only refreshes token when necessary
                String accessToken = accessToken1.getToken(); //get token as String
                HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
                headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
                return execution.execute(request, body);
        };
        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        template.setInterceptors(List.of(clientHttpRequestInterceptor));
        return template;
    }
}
```

Here a unit test that demonstrates the usage:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class OAuth2ClientTest {
    @Autowired
    KeycloakRestTemplateFactory keycloakRestTemplateFactory;

    @Test
    void oauth2ClientTestSuccessful() {
        RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate = keycloakRestTemplateFactory.oauth2RestTemplate("admin", "admin");
        oauth2RestTemplate.put("http://localhost:8080/api/keystore/wetter/windig", null);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = oauth2RestTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/api/keystore/wetter", String.class);
        String body = response.getBody();
        assertEquals("windig", body);
    }

    @Test
    void oauth2ClientTestInsufficientRights() {
        assertThrows(HttpClientErrorException.Forbidden.class, () -> {
            RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate = keycloakRestTemplateFactory.oauth2RestTemplate("user", "user");
            oauth2RestTemplate.put("http://localhost:8080/api/keystore/wetter/windig", null);
        });
    }

    @Test
    void oauth2ClientTestWrongPassword() {
        assertThrows(NotAuthorizedException.class, () -> {
            RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate = keycloakRestTemplateFactory.oauth2RestTemplate("user", "wrongpassword");
            oauth2RestTemplate.put("http://localhost:8080/api/keystore/wetter/windig", null);
        });
    }
}
```